# Python to exe - hydra: No module named 'hydra._internal.core_plugins'

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe, hydra

I have a Python script (3.9.8) which work fine in the cli (on Win11). Now I want to take my python script and generate a `.exe`. I did it once with hydra without any problems. Now after the convert I do get this error message from Hydra (1.2.0).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\main.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "hydra\main.py", line 90, in decorated_main
  File "hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 332, in _run_hydra
  File "hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 183, in create_automatic_config_search_path
  File "hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 196, in create_config_search_path
  File "hydra\core\plugins.py", line 46, in instance
  File "hydra\core\singleton.py", line 17, in instance
  File "hydra\core\singleton.py", line 13, in __call__
  File "hydra\core\plugins.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "hydra\core\plugins.py", line 58, in _initialize
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hydra._internal.core_plugins'
```

This is my project structure

```
src
│   main.py
│
├───conf
│   │   config.yaml
│   │   __init__.py
│   └───hydra
│       └───job_logging
│               logging.yaml
│
└───logs
```

I am using the `auto-py-to-exe` module. Modules are in an env, I include the path to the site-packages. I am using the version 2.23.1
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --paths "D:/Programmieren/Python/StorageRoom/.venv/Lib/site-packages"  "D:/Programmieren/Python/StorageRoom/src/main.py"`

This is the code I am using which gets me the error.

```py
from omegaconf import DictConfig
import traceback
import sys
import hydra
import logging


@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../conf", config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    log = logging.getLogger(__file__)
    log.info("This is a very nice print from the exe")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        sys.exit(-1)
```

**config.yaml**

```yaml
defaults:
  - override hydra/job_logging: logging
  - _self_

hydra:
  output_subdir: null  
  run:  
    dir: .
```

**logging.yaml**

```yaml
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  logFormatter: 
    format: '%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(module)s-%(lineno)4s | %(levelname)-8s | %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:                                                            
    class: logging.FileHandler                                     
    formatter: logFormatter                                              
    filename: logs/${hydra.job.name}.log     
root:
  handlers: [console, file]
  level: INFO

disable_existing_loggers: false
```

This is my output folder structure
This is my project structure

```
output
│   main.exe
│
├───conf
│   │   config.yaml
│   │   __init__.py
│   └───hydra
│       └───job_logging
│               logging.yaml
│
└───logs
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there's a bug in `auto-py-to-exe` that is incompatible with Python's `importlib.import_module` function.

Looking at the stacktrace you posted, I see `File "hydra\core\plugins.py", line 58, in _initialize`. Looking at [line 58 `hydra/core/plugins.py` in the Hydra source repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/66c3b37bffde8a0b00258d032505eef7b5720fd4/hydra/core/plugins.py#L58), I see there's a call to `importlib.import_module`.

It seems there is an open issue in the `auto-py-to-exe` repo (https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/325), and several closed issues (see e.g. https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/177), that mention trouble with `importlib.import_module`.